# Dialog box in android

Tags: android, dialog, progressdialog

By default dialog freezes whole screen but my requirement is when dialog appears then particular layout should be freeze rather than whole screen. Is this possible? If yes, then please post your comments and answer.

Comment: When you say freezed, you mean inactive?

Comment: I meant that when dialog appears then whole activity goes in background but i want only particular layout should go in background rather then whole activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if user forcefully stops the dialog then he can be do this by clicking on the button on the screen

is there any requirement to do this? if you set the dialog to be cancelable, the user is able to leave the dialog using the back button anyways...

Comment: According to my requirement there is two button on the top bar of the Acitivity to go back to previous screen and next screen. If user want to skip the downloading and go forward then he can be navigate by clicking on the navigation buttons on the top of screen. But from the back key he can only cancel the dialog.

Comment: You should be able to add custom buttons to a dialog. One of these buttons can be "cancel and continue" or similar.

Comment: i do it by make the whole screen custom.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean to be honest.

A dialog box shows a view which holds the dialog, and a view behind that which prevents touches to the view behind. You can always create your own custom dialog which will not include the interim view and allow touches behind it. I'm not sure why you would want to do this though, I think you've misunderstood the purpose of the dialog, and you should be using a custom element anyway.

Comment: I agree with you that dialog prevents touches to the view behind and it should be. But my requirement is that if user forcefully stops the dialog then he can be do this by clicking on the button on the screen.Is this possible?